# Return array of urls from pages for which the content matches pattern

Tags: javascript

How would you return an array of urls from pages for which the corresponding content matches pattern?

Currently my code only returns one string.

```
function urls(pages, pattern) {
  var i, l, page, arr;
  for(i=0, l=pages.length; i<l; i++) {
    page = pages[i];
    arr = page.split(page[0]);
    if(arr[2].indexOf(pattern) >=0) {
      return arr[1];
    }
  }
  return '';
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It only returns one string because you're returning it as soon as you find it. You probably want to collect the found strings into an array and return that:

```
function urls(pages, pattern) {
  var i, l, page, arr, result = [];
  for(i=0, l=pages.length; i<l; i++) {
    page = pages[i];
    arr = page.split(page[0]);
    if(arr[2].indexOf(pattern) >=0) {
      result.push(arr[1]);
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```